# How to access the attribute name when using a class as an enum?

Tags: python

I have a class representing an Enum:

```
class Colors():
   red = 1
   blue = 2
   green = 3
```

I can access the value using the attribute name, e.g. `Colors.red`

How can I go in the reverse direction to get the attribute name based on the index?

I know using classes like this as a makeshift enum may not be the best way to create an enum in Python, so please treat this question as academic and please focus on providing an answer to the question.

At this stage I'm wondering if it is possible to achieve my goal **without** using the **enum.Enum** class.

Comment: why this question has been closed? the OP specifically mentions `not be the best way to create an enum in Python, so please treat this question as academic`, I do not think is a duplicate of the mentioned answer

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the OP doesn't want to use the built-in Enum the documentation provided doesn't really help in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for your class `Colors` you can use:

```
r = {v: k for k, v in Colors.__dict__.items()}
r[1]
# 'red'
```

this will not work if the values are not hashable